# EXC_BAD_ACCESS ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

Please help me to find out the reason why crash.I known had many question with the same title but with I cannot find out solution for my problem. My problem is my app crash(Bad Access) with ios7, with old version it work ok. This is my code:

```
- (void)updateLine:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    BOOL registered =[(notification.userInfo)[kRADialePushViewNotificationRegistration] boolValue];
    if (!registered) {
        if (self.navigationController) {// it crash this line
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem here is: self.navigationController is nil. But I don't know why ios7 don't accept for access a nil navigationController while I can do it on ios6 or older. My solution is check if the view is current view (it's my DND view), I call popViewController, because if the view is current view you can get self.navigationController which have value not nil.My code is:

```
- (void)updateLine:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    BOOL registered =[(notification.userInfo)[kRADialePushViewNotificationRegistration] boolValue];
    if (!registered) {
        if (self.isloaded && self.view.window){
          if (self.navigationController) {
              [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
           }
         }
    }
}
```